# fwrite(, append = TRUE) appends wrong way

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite

I am facing a problem with the fwrite function from the DataTable package in R. In fact it appends the wrong way and I'd end up with something like:

```
**user  ref version status  Type    DataExtraction**                    
user1   2.02E+11    1   Pending 1   No                  
user2   2.02E+11    1   Saved   2   No"user3"   2.01806E+11 1   Saved   NB  No
```

I am using the function as follows :

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(Save, "~/Downloads/Register.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = TRUE)
```

Reproducible example:

```
fwrite(data.table(user="user3", 
                  ref="204094093", 
                  version="2", 
                  status="Pending", 
                  Type="1",DataExtraction="No"),
       "~/Downloads/test.csv", sep = ",", append = FALSE)

fwrite(data.table(user="user3", 
                  ref="204094093", 
                  version="2", 
                  status="Pending", 
                  Type="1",DataExtraction="No"),
       "~/Downloads/test.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE)
```

I'm not sure if it isolates the problem, but it seems that if I manually change something in the .csv file (for instance rename DataExtraction to Extraction), the problem of appending in the wrong way occurs.
Does someone know what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with the output you're currently seeing

Comment: Well this: ' "user3"   2.01806E+11 1   Saved   NB  No' should have been printed on a new line. Yet it appended on the second observation.

Comment: please add some information about your environment -- operating system, r version, data.table package version (all of this is in `sessionInfo()`). including the output of dput(Save) for the objects your trying to write would help as well

Comment: R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23), Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit), Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3, data.table_1.11.4

Comment: Output of Save I am writing would be something like : data.table("user3", 04094093, 2, "Pending", "1","No")

Comment: While you're at it, please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your example code I have no problems with the behavior - the file comes out as desired.  Based on your comments about manually changing what is in the file, and what the undesired output looks like, here is what I believe is happening.  When `fwrite()` (and many other similar IO functions) write to a file, each line has at the end of it a line break (in R, this is generally represented as `\n`).  This is desired, so that subsequent lines of data indeed appear on subsequent lines of the file.  Generally this will also mean that when you open a file in a text editor, there will be a blank line at the very end, since this reflects the line break in the last line that was written.  (different editors handle this differently though).  So, I suspect what is happening is that when you go in and manually edit the file in your editor, you are somehow losing that last line break.  What this means is that when you go to write again using append, there is no line break at the end of the file, and therefore you get the undesired behavior of two lines of data on a single line of the file.

So, the solution would be to either find how to prevent your manual editing from deleting that last line break character.  Barring that, there are ways to just write a single line break character to the file using R.  E.g. with the `cat()` function.

Comment: I have a similar problem and in my case the new line character "\n" is also read into a single line. So now the last line of appended fwrite just increases the size of the last column of the last line without actually incrementing any lines. Am I missing anything? I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra can you give some reproducible code illustrating your problem?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I have for now solved the problem by removing a bunch of lines and again appending to the file successfully. Perhaps there were some offending characters in those lines like HTML tags that could be confusing fwrite.